# How to convert new line from textarea to the div? Without replace to "<br>"

Tags: html, replace, textarea, newline

How to convert new line from textarea to the div? Cant be replaced to the `<br>` because I writting articles with codes like PHP, HTML, CSS and others and the codes is in `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags. If I replace new line `\r\n` with `<br>`, the replace the code too, and that is not good.

### Example of my problem

I write to `<textarea>` this:

```
    <b>Strong Text</b>
    Normal text

    Code:
    <pre>
    <b>Strong text</b>
    Normal text
    </pre>
```

Now, I need in `<div>` show result of content in textarea. **IF I REPLACE** `\r\n` WITH `<br>` I got in `<div>` this:

```
    <b>Strong Text</b><br>
    Normal text<br>
    <br>
    Code:<br>
    <pre><br>
    <b>Strong text</b><br>
    Normal text<br>
    </pre>
```

I must replace all `<br>`-s in the `<pre>` with `\r\n`, and other `<br>`-s **NOT REPLACE**

### I need get this to `<div>`

```
    <b>Strong Text</b><br>
    Normal text<br>
    <br>
    Code:<br>
    <pre>\r\n
    <b>Strong text</b>\r\n
    Normal text\r\n
    </pre>
```

`\r\n` = new line

Comment: What's wrong with using `<pre>`? 3-5 line sample of text you are trying to format would be helpful.

Comment: I edit my ask with example

Comment: OK. I deleted my answer as it not going to help. I'd recommend to change sample to "here is text, I want following HTML as result" (include all cases of BR/new line replacing in the sample). Also add language(s) tags you want the code in.

Comment: sorry dont understand, I need replace `<br>` between `<pre>` and `</pre>`

Comment: no help? i dont understand your answer